# How to detect if the current process is being run by GDB

Tags: c, linux, gdb, posix

The standard way would be the following:

```
if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, 0) == -1)
  printf("traced!\n");
```

In this case, ptrace returns an error if the current process is traced (e.g., running it with GDB or attaching to it).

But there is a serious problem with this: if the call returns successfully, GDB may not attach to it later. Which is a problem since I'm not trying to implement anti-debug stuff. My purpose is to emit an 'int 3' when a condition is met (e.g., an assert fails) and GDB is running (otherwise I get a SIGTRAP which stops the application).

Disabling SIGTRAP and emitting an 'int 3' every time is not a good solution because the application I'm testing might be using SIGTRAP for some other purpose (in which case I'm still screwed, so it wouldn't matter, but it's the principle of the thing :))

Comment: You must find something like IsDebuggerPresent on POSIX

Comment: @Svisstack: Yes, that my question is roughly what that POSIX call/method would be.

Comment: You could fork a child which would try to `PTRACE_ATTACH` its parent (and then detach if necessary) and communicates the result back. It does seem a bit inelegant though.

Comment: @Huw: That worked, thanks. If you write an answer I'll accept it. But the forking makes it rather costly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could fork a child which would try to `PTRACE_ATTACH` its parent (and then detach if necessary) and communicates the result back. It does seem a bit inelegant though.

As you mention, this is quite costly. I guess it's not too bad if assertions fail irregularly. Perhaps it'd be worthwhile keeping a single long-running child around to do this - share two pipes between the parent and the child, child does its check when it reads a byte and then sends a byte back with the status.

Answer (score 54):

On Windows there is an API, IsDebuggerPresent, to check if process is under debugging. At Linux, we can check this with another way (not so efficient).

Check "**/proc/self/status**" for "**TracerPid**" attribute.

Example code:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool debuggerIsAttached()
{
    char buf[4096];

    const int status_fd = open("/proc/self/status", O_RDONLY);
    if (status_fd == -1)
        return false;

    const ssize_t num_read = read(status_fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
    close(status_fd);

    if (num_read <= 0)
        return false;

    buf[num_read] = '\0';
    constexpr char tracerPidString[] = "TracerPid:";
    const auto tracer_pid_ptr = strstr(buf, tracerPidString);
    if (!tracer_pid_ptr)
        return false;

    for (const char* characterPtr = tracer_pid_ptr + sizeof(tracerPidString) - 1; characterPtr <= buf + num_read; ++characterPtr)
    {
        if (isspace(*characterPtr))
            continue;
        else
            return isdigit(*characterPtr) != 0 && *characterPtr != '0';
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is "TracerPid" field of `/proc/self/status` available on every version of the Linux Kernel?

Comment: @osgx. Did some quick check, the “TracerPid” is added by linux procfs at least since 2005 or even earlier. Also, I noticed that gdb & google perftools use same way to get or check the tracer pid.

Comment: @SamLiao: `buf[num_read] = 0;` writes past the end of `buf` if `sizeof(buf)` bytes are read from the file. Might I suggest you pass `sizeof(buf) - 1` to the call to `read` to fix this?

Comment: On Linux, above code also required including <unistd.h> (read) and <cstdlib> (atoi).

Comment: I propose upping `buf`'s size to 4096 instead of 1024 just to be on the safe side. The size of the `"/proc/self/status"` is 1401 in my case, and who's to say `TracerPid` is guaranteed to be in the upper 1024 symbols? I also propose the following optimization: we don't need `atoi`, we only need to check that the first non-whitespace symbol of the PID is a digit and is not `'0'`. I've edited the answer with my suggestions. And I included the missing header file.

Answer (score 23):

The code I ended up using was the following:

```
int
gdb_check()
{
  int pid = fork();
  int status;
  int res;

  if (pid == -1)
  {
    perror("fork");
    return -1;
  }

  if (pid == 0)
  {
    int ppid = getppid();

    /* Child */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ppid, NULL, NULL) == 0)
    {
      /* Wait for the parent to stop and continue it */
      waitpid(ppid, NULL, 0);
      ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, NULL, NULL);

      /* Detach */
      ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, getppid(), NULL, NULL);

      /* We were the tracers, so gdb is not present */
      res = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      /* Trace failed so GDB is present */
      res = 1;
    }
    exit(res);
  }
  else
  {
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    res = WEXITSTATUS(status);
  }
  return res;
}
```

A few things:

- When ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...) is successful, the traced process will stop and has to be continued.
- This also works when GDB is attaching later.
- A drawback is that when used frequently, it will cause a serious slowdown.
- Also, this solution is only confirmed to work on Linux. As the comments mentioned, it won't work on [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution).

Comment: Your second call to ptrace is missing the pid parameter

Comment: Better use _Exit instead of exit, or some exit handler might cause chaos.

Comment: This doesn't work on OSX (and presumably BSD) due to waitpid being interrupted with EINTR. See a fixed typo free version below...

Comment: Confirmed not to work on BSD. PTRACE_CONT is also superfluous, detach will automatically cause the traced process to continue.

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell: thanks for the info, I updated the answer. OTOH I left the PTRACE_CONT in, I find it better to do these things explicitly.

Comment: @terminus Sure. It only caused issues for me because of BSD weirdness that seems to require the parent process be suspended before the child writes to the pipe, else the parent gets a SIGKILL.

Comment: This is nice, but to work the child needs permissions to attach to its parent (by default it is the other way around: parents are allowed to trace their children), so `#include <sys/prctl.h>`, and then somewhere `prctl(PR_SET_PTRACER, (unsigned long)getpid(), 0, 0, 0);` (this allows ptrace from ourselves and our descendants - i.a. the new child from your solution).

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar need, and came up with the following alternatives

```
static int _debugger_present = -1;
static void _sigtrap_handler(int signum)
{
    _debugger_present = 0;
    signal(SIGTRAP, SIG_DFL);
}

void debug_break(void)
{
    if (-1 == _debugger_present) {
        _debugger_present = 1;
        signal(SIGTRAP, _sigtrap_handler);
        raise(SIGTRAP);
    }
}
```

If called, the debug_break function will only interrupt if a debugger is attached.

If you are running on x86 and want a breakpoint which interrupts in the caller (not in *raise*), just include the following header, and use the debug_break macro:

```
#ifndef BREAK_H
#define BREAK_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

int _debugger_present = -1;
static void _sigtrap_handler(int signum)
{
    _debugger_present = 0;
    signal(SIGTRAP, SIG_DFL);
}

#define debug_break()                       \
do {                                        \
    if (-1 == _debugger_present) {          \
        _debugger_present = 1;              \
        signal(SIGTRAP, _sigtrap_handler);  \
        __asm__("int3");                    \
    }                                       \
} while(0)

#endif
```

Comment: This is a great answer. To clarify how it works, if the debugger is attached then when you `raise(SIGTRAP)` it will intercept the signal instead of going to your `_sigtrap_handler`. There is a big downside in that if the debugger *is* attached then it will break into the debugger. That's probably fine if your use case is "wait for a debugger", rather than "check if a debugger is attached".

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to know whether the application is running under GDB for debugging purposes, the simplest solution on Linux is to `readlink("/proc/<ppid>/exe")`, and search the result for `"gdb"`.

Comment: Thanks, but it will not work when gdb attaches after the program is already running.

Answer (score 6):

I found that a modified version of the file descriptor "hack" [described by Silviocesare](http://silviocesare.wordpress.com/2008/05/13/gdb-leaves-file-descriptors-open-in-debugee/) and [blogged by xorl](http://xorl.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/more-gdb-anti-debugging/) worked well for me.

This is the modified code I use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// gdb apparently opens FD(s) 3,4,5 (whereas a typical prog uses only stdin=0, stdout=1,stderr=2)
int detect_gdb(void)
{
    int rc = 0;
    FILE *fd = fopen("/tmp", "r");

    if (fileno(fd) > 5)
    {
        rc = 1;
    }

    fclose(fd);
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: @franz1 interesting. thanks for the comment. i just built GDB 7.10 at home recently, so i will test and code-read and try to update this. many thanks.

Comment: This probably has too many false positives.  File descriptors can be leaked for many reasons.  Even well-known open-source programs sometimes do (e.g. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde4libs/+bug/385999 )

Comment: Seems not to work anymore.

Answer (score 6):

This is similar to [terminus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596781/how-to-detect-if-the-current-process-is-being-run-by-gdb/3599394#3599394), but uses pipes for communication:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#if !defined(PTRACE_ATTACH) && defined(PT_ATTACH)
#  define PTRACE_ATTACH PT_ATTACH
#endif
#if !defined(PTRACE_DETACH) && defined(PT_DETACH)
#  define PTRACE_DETACH PT_DETACH
#endif

#ifdef __linux__
#  define _PTRACE(_x, _y) ptrace(_x, _y, NULL, NULL)
#else
#  define _PTRACE(_x, _y) ptrace(_x, _y, NULL, 0)
#endif

/** Determine if we're running under a debugger by attempting to attach using pattach
 *
 * @return 0 if we're not, 1 if we are, -1 if we can't tell.
 */
static int debugger_attached(void)
{
    int pid;

    int from_child[2] = {-1, -1};

    if (pipe(from_child) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Debugger check failed: Error opening internal pipe: %s", syserror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Debugger check failed: Error forking: %s", syserror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    /* Child */
    if (pid == 0) {
        uint8_t ret = 0;
        int ppid = getppid();

        /* Close parent's side */
        close(from_child[0]);

        if (_PTRACE(PTRACE_ATTACH, ppid) == 0) {
            /* Wait for the parent to stop */
            waitpid(ppid, NULL, 0);

            /* Tell the parent what happened */
            write(from_child[1], &ret, sizeof(ret));

            /* Detach */
            _PTRACE(PTRACE_DETACH, ppid);
            exit(0);
        }

        ret = 1;
        /* Tell the parent what happened */
        write(from_child[1], &ret, sizeof(ret));

        exit(0);
    /* Parent */
    } else {
        uint8_t ret = -1;

        /*
         *    The child writes a 1 if pattach failed else 0.
         *
         *    This read may be interrupted by pattach,
         *    which is why we need the loop.
         */
        while ((read(from_child[0], &ret, sizeof(ret)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));

        /* Ret not updated */
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Debugger check failed: Error getting status from child: %s", syserror(errno));
        }

        /* Close the pipes here, to avoid races with pattach (if we did it above) */
        close(from_child[1]);
        close(from_child[0]);

        /* Collect the status of the child */
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Trying the original code under OS X, I found waitpid (in the parent) would always return -1 with an EINTR (System call interrupted). This was caused by pattach, attaching to the parent and interrupting the call.

It wasn't clear whether it was safe to just call waitpid again (that seemed like it might behave incorrectly in some situations), so I just used a pipe to do the communication instead. It's a bit of extra code, but will probably work reliably across more platforms.

This code has been tested on [OS X v10.9.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks), [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) (3.13.0-24-generic) and [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) 10.0.

For Linux, which implements process capabilities, this method will only work if the process has the `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability, which is typically set when the process is run as root.

Other utilities (`gdb` and `lldb`) also have this capability set as part of their filesystem metadata.

You can detect whether the process has effective `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` by linking against `-lcap`,

```
#include <sys/capability.h>

cap_flag_value_t value;
cap_t current;

/*
 *  If we're running under Linux, we first need to check if we have
 *  permission to to ptrace. We do that using the capabilities
 *  functions.
 */
current = cap_get_proc();
if (!current) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed getting process capabilities: %s\n", syserror(errno));
    return -1;
}

if (cap_get_flag(current, CAP_SYS_PTRACE, CAP_PERMITTED, &value) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed getting permitted ptrace capability state: %s\n", syserror(errno));
    cap_free(current);
    return -1;
}

if ((value == CAP_SET) && (cap_get_flag(current, CAP_SYS_PTRACE, CAP_EFFECTIVE, &value) < 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed getting effective ptrace capability state: %s\n", syserror(errno));
    cap_free(current);
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ version of [Sam Liao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596781/how-to-detect-if-the-current-process-is-being-run-by-gdb/24969863#24969863) (Linux only):

```
// Detect if the application is running inside a debugger.
bool being_traced()
{
  std::ifstream sf("/proc/self/status");
  std::string s;
  while (sf >> s)
  {
    if (s == "TracerPid:")
    {
      int pid;
      sf >> pid;
      return pid != 0;
    }
    std::getline(sf, s);
  }

  return false;
}
```