# C# Anti-Debug method OutputDebugString doesn't work right

Tags: c#, debugging, pinvoke, windbg, native-code

So recently I've been reading up on anti-debug mechanisms and a popular method I've come across to check if the current process is being debugged is `OutputDebugString`. I've written this piece of code but it doesn't exactly work as intended can someone shed some light on why or what I'm doing wrong?

```
private static bool stub_OutputDebugString()
{
    uint ErrCode = 0x12A6;
    Native.SetLastError(ErrCode);
    Native.OutputDebugString("System.Core\n");
    if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == (int)ErrCode)
    {
        //Debugger Detected
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //No Debugger Detected
        return false;
    }
}
```

My P/Invoke signatures

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void SetLastError(uint dwErrCode);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void OutputDebugString(string lpOutputString);
```

Note I readup on how `GetLastError` shouldn't be called from the native environment as the value can be changed so I'm using `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`

The code should work but the last error doesn't change when i try to debug the application with windbg or any other debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning about `GetLastError()` (it shouldn't be used because last error may be overwritten *by .NET Framework* because of any other internal/invisible/background operation) **also applies** to `SetLastError()`. Simply you can't reliably call it and expect its value is preserved intact until you call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`.

We may discuss how to circumvent this issue however...

...that technique has (somehow) sense for native code because `OutputDebugString()` is widely used and disassembling compiled code is harder (then you *protect* yourself with some *obfuscated code*). However managed code is easy to decompile and it's still easy to read and understand, such simple obfuscation will not help and you should simply go with `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` property.

---

If you really really want to detect a debugger (even if it's very easy to see what you're doing then it won't offer much protection) you have to
make things more complicate because you may want to protect against a managed debugger or a native debugger. Yes they're different.

Unless managed debugger is built on top of native one if you call native `IsDebuggerPresent()` you will always get `FALSE` for a managed debugger where `Debugger.IsAttached` would return `true`. Also opposite scenario is true: with a native debugger attached you will get `TRUE` from `IsDebuggerPresent()` but `false` from `Debugger.IsAttached`. In the big world you will meet all three types of debugger. For a better discussion about `IsDebuggerPresent()` you may read [Anti-Debugging](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/anti-debugging/).

You may check both but you're still far from detecting debuggers because they only check for local managed/native debuggers but you don't have information about remote debuggers (unless you also call `CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent()`) or debuggers that don't live in user-mode (unless you also play with `NtQuerySystemInformation`). There are some slightly more robust techniques but you can't do it in managed world (see also [Detecting System Debugger](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/anti-debugging-detecting-system-debugger/)).

One possible solution is to debug your own process using `DebugActiveProcess()`, it you fail (and it's not a permission error) then another debugger is attached, moreover until you stay attached another debugger can't attach. Note that a process can not debug itself (AFAIK) then it must be done from a child process (which somehow communicate with main process you want to *protect*). It's nothing new, basically the same technique described in [How to detect if the current process is being run by GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3596781/1207195) but Windows specific.

Read see also [Debuggers aren't supposed to change behavior](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2004/10/02/236942.aspx) and [Managed vs. Native debugging APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/07/03/managed-vs-native-apis.aspx) for more information about this topic.

Comment: I'm aware of the fact native code can be decompiled and seen. But thats another issue. Things like IsDebuggerPresent and such are trivial to bypass to but I would like to check for most of them even though a simple hook would bypass it.

Comment: You didn't get my point. The only reason to use OutputDebugString() over IsDebuggerPresent() - in native code - is to **OBFUSCATE** this check. It's not better or more reliable nor safer. In managed code this obfuscation is meaningless because when you decompile it...you even have pretty formatted source code. Back to your main question then: you can't do like this because SetLastError() won't work. However side question would be: why do you need it? Do you want to prevent debugging...why?

Comment: Yes the main goal is to prevent or hinger the debugging of my native process employing as many different techniques as possible.

Comment: woops ment managed I've looked at obfuscaters out there for .NET applications such as confuserEx and learn't a few tricks just trying to comprehend a decent way to stop debugging thanks for your response though was informative.

Comment: No, my _question_ is different. I see you want to stop debugging, I would know why you need it. Code is deployed and executed on client computer then, unless you have a DRM enabled device, it doesn't matter how much effort you put on that...they can inspect, change and eventually debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use the [IsDebuggerPresent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345(v=vs.85).aspx) function?.. I believe is exists for the purpose you want.

Comment: Yes, it's easier but it doesn't check for remote debuggers and for non user-mode debuggers.